# Telerik - uncheck command is not unchecking the checkbox

Tags: checkbox, telerik

I have a radio button that I try to uncheck, but it is not working.

```
        if (toggleButton.IsChecked != false)
        {
            toggleButton.UnCheck(true);
        }
        return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
toggleButton.CheckState=CheckState.Unchecked;
```